# Error installing SQlite during installation of Beef in windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I am trying to install BEEF in Windows 10 PC by following the instructions given here:
https://github.com/beefproject/beef/wiki/Installation

I am stuck in the last step while doing `bundle install`.
I keep on getting this error:

```
Installing do_sqlite3 0.10.17 with native extensions

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    E:/Ruby22-x64/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20160814-9372-uyjql9.rb extconf.rb
checking for sqlite3.h... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=E:/Ruby22-x64/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
        --with-sqlite3-dir
        --without-sqlite3-dir
        --with-sqlite3-include
        --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
        --with-sqlite3-lib
        --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in E:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/do_sqlite3-0.10.17 for inspection.
Results logged to E:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.2.0/do_sqlite3-0.10.17/gem_make.out
Using dm-do-adapter 1.2.0
Using dm-migrations 1.2.0
Using dm-serializer 1.2.2
Using qr4r 0.4.1
Using sinatra 1.4.7
Using rubydns 0.7.3
An error occurred while installing do_sqlite3 (0.10.17), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install do_sqlite3 -v '0.10.17'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I have tried all workarounds I got by searching the web, like compiling the header file from source and running `gem install sqlite3`. But none of them work.

Comment: The Windows installation instructions contains a very important line that you might have missed: *"Windows is no longer supported. The following instructions are outdated."*

Comment: @marsatomic: Uh... sorry, I overlooked that.  So does that mean BEEF can no longer be installed in windows?

Comment: While I'm pretty good at reading, I'm no expert on BEEF. What I'd recommend in this case is to install virtualbox so that you can run a *nix environment within Windows. This should allow you to avoid any number of potential problems with Rails and Windows. Most gem authors compile for and with *nix tools, and you can run into weird things under Windows.